# Thunder Client error, but Postman works ok

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

Why does In Postman client work , but not ThunderClient ?

In Postman client , I can GET to http://localhost:5173/api/posts , and see body "message":"Hello" , and status 200

But when I try the same  operation using Thunder client extension in VS Code , I get **"Connection was refused by the server."**

I also tried using http://127.0.0.1:5173/api/posts
and http://192.168.1.125:5173/api/posts
, but no luck with either one.

Comment: might not be possible to know without knowing more about this server of yours.

Comment: I run the "server" by : npm run dev <-- SvelteKit app.

Comment: What am I missing ? Is there a firewall setting in VS CODE ?

Comment: I got it to work by using : [::1]:5173/api/posts 
not sure why it works>

Comment: what's in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))? and what OS are you on? Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses

Answer (score 0):

using : [::1]  instead of localhost

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).